# List of tuples from original list

Tags: python

I have a list `[6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]`

and would like to create a new list of pairs that looks like this:

```
[(7,63),(64,131),(132,182),(183,507),(508,659),(660,669)]
```

When I use the below code:

```
list = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]
line_num = 0
for idx,i in enumerate(list):
    print(list[idx]+1,list[idx+1])
```

I get below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
      5     pass
      6 else:
----> 7     print(city_index[idx]+1,city_index[idx+1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I end the loop before I get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slicing, and it returns everything of the message but the last element ie :-1

```
list = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]
line_num = 0
for idx,i in enumerate(list[:-1]):
    print(list[idx]+1,list[idx+1])
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `zip` instead. This frees you from worrying about list indices (for the most part).

```
lst = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]

for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    print(x+1, y)
```

If you don't like the idea of making a shallow copy of `lst`, use `itertools.islice` instead.

```
from itertools import islice


lst = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]

for x, y in zip(lst, islice(lst, 1, None)):
    print(x+1, y)
```

Or, use `itertools.pairwise`, introduced in Python 3.10

```
for x, y in pairwise(lst):
    print(x+1, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]
new_l = []
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    new_l.append((l[i-1] + 1, l[i]))
print(new_l)
```

output:

```
[(7, 63), (64, 131), (132, 182), (183, 507), (508, 659), (660, 669)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop until the length of the list - 1 to avoid out of range:

```
lst = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]

pairs = []
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    pairs.append((lst[i]+1, lst[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
nums = [6, 63, 131, 182, 507, 659, 669]
pairs = [(nums[i] + 1, nums[i + 1]) for i in range(len(nums) - 1)]
```

You could do this in a list comprehension and stop the loop at `len(nums) - 1` instead of `len(nums)`. You probably don't want to call a variable `list` because that's a special word in python.